# Cyclic permutation and Poisson brackets

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, permutation-cycles

Consider the cyclic permutation operator $\tau$ defined as
$$\tau(x_1,...,x_N)=(x_2,...,x_N,x_1)$$
and denote

$$ (\tau f) (x,y) = f(\tau x,\tau y).$$

A cyclically symmetric function is a function $F$ such that $\tau F=F$.

For the Poisson bracket between two cyclically symmetric function we have

$$\sum_{s,s'} \{\tau^s f, \tau^{s'} g \} = \sum_s \tau^s\big(\sum_{s'} \{f,\tau^{s'}g\} \big).$$

I can't figure out the last equality, that is: when do I exploit the cyclically symmetric property? How the partial derivatives change with these permutation?

Comment: What is your definition of Poisson brackets?

Comment: @enzotib given two function $f(x_1,...,x_N,y_1,...,y_N),g(x_1,...,x_N,y_1,...,y_N)$ the Poisson bracket between $f$ and $g$ is $$\{f,g\}=\sum_{k=1,...,N} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y_k}-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y_k}\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x_k} $$

Comment: I agree, but why in your question $f,g$ seem to be functions of only $x_1,\ldots,x_N$?

Comment: You right, my mistake.

Comment: $\tau^2f$ means $\tau(\tau f)$ and so on? If so, on which values are extended the sums on $s,s'$?

Comment: @enzotib $s,s'=1,...,N$